# Reversing a doubly linked list returns nothing

Tags: c, doubly-linked-list

I am trying to reverse elements in a doubly linked list and I cannot seem to reverse the elements in the list. It keeps showing a blank list. After entering the nodes in the list and printing them out, this function is supposed to reverse the nodes in the list but when printing it it shows blank. (no segmentation faults)

This is the function:

```
void reverse(List it) {
    Node *temp;
    Node *corr;
    temp = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    corr = malloc(sizeof(Node));

    corr = it->curr;

    while (corr != NULL) {
        temp = corr->prev;
        corr->prev = corr->next;
        corr->next = temp;  
        corr = corr->prev;
    }
}
```

Comment: If it's doubly linked, is there any need to reverse it? You can traverse it both ways without modifying it at all.

Comment: I need to reverse the elements that are stored in these nodes so i have to reverse them

Comment: nothing about traverse its like the list has 12 ,20, 17, 30 i need to reverse the elments to 30, 17, 20, 12

Comment: What does `it->curr` point to at the beginning of this function?

Comment: The `it->curr` points to the current element that its pointing in the list.And the elements suppose to like swap without changing the current position.

Comment: Also you’re setting `temp` to `corr-> next` then setting `corr->prev` to next then setting `corr-> next` to temp which current point to `corr->next` shouldn’t you be setting next to prev?

Comment: basically it can point to any element but it just swaps without changing the position

Comment: Hi there i made changes but the error still persist

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] demonstrating the empty output.

Comment: Like when i call `reverse(it)` in the main function,the output is empty and no result

Comment: Did you try putting a `printf` statement inside the loop to see what was happening?  - and I don't see why you need the `malloc`statements as you just have pointers....

Comment: Note that you've leaked the memory allocated to `corr` when you do `corr = it->curr;`  You leak the memory allocated to `temp` if you enter the loop and do `temp = corr->prev;`.  You don't attempt to free what you allocated, which is just as well since it has been leaked.  You shouldn't need any memory allocation in the function; you just need a few pointer variables.

Comment: Make it circular and just traverse backwards. Example of circular double linked list I did is here: https://pastebin.com/mScMkkdy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 problems in your code:

- there is no need to allocate new nodes, in fact these allocated nodes are lost when you store new values to `corr` and `temp`.
- you must update the `it->curr` to point to the first node of the reversed list, that is the last node of the original list

Here is a corrected version:

```
void reverse(List it) {
    Node *last = NULL;
    Node *corr = it->curr;

    while (corr != NULL) {
        Node *temp = corr->prev;
        corr->prev = corr->next;
        corr->next = temp; 
        last = corr; 
        corr = corr->prev;
    }
    it->curr = last;
}
```

Note also that it is considered bad style and error prone to hide pointers behind typedefs. `List` is a typedef for a pointer, but a confused reader may at first believe that you pass a structure by value to the `reverse` function...

Answer (score 1):

After thinking about this I suggest the following new function based on your old one might possibly work, but it is a bit of a guess... - key change is new line in loop see snippet below

```
  while(corr!=NULL)
   {

     temp=corr->prev;
     corr->prev=corr->next;
     corr->next=temp;  
     it->curr=corr;  //this should make the last member the new first member
     corr=corr->prev;

    }
```

This is a little bit inelegant as `it->corr` will keep changing every cycle of the loop, but when it finished `it->corr` should have the first member of the list - and that might make your print statement work, but as I said above it is a bit of a guess.

I removed `malloc` as it is not needed

working version - full program to test below

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Node{
  struct Node * prev;
  struct Node * next;
  int ndata;
};

struct List {
  struct Node node[20];
  struct Node * curr;
};


void reverse(struct List *);
void printlist(struct List *);

int main()
{
  struct List it;

  int n;

  for (n=0;n<20;n++)  //set up a simple double linked list
    {
      it.node[n].ndata=n;
      if (n>1) 
    {
      it.node[n].prev=&(it.node[n-1]);
    }
      else
    {
      it.node[n].prev=NULL;
    }
      if (n<19) 
    {
      it.node[n].next=&(it.node[n+1]);
    }
      else
    {
      it.node[n].next=NULL;
    }
    }
  it.curr=&(it.node[0]);

  printlist(&it);
  reverse(&it);
  printlist(&it);
}

void printlist(struct List * it)
{

  struct Node *corr;

  corr = it->curr;

  while(corr!=NULL)
    {
      printf("%d\n",corr->ndata);
      corr=corr->next;
    }
  return;
}
void reverse(struct List * it)
{

  struct Node *temp;
  struct Node *corr;

  corr = it->curr;

  while(corr!=NULL)
    {
      temp=corr->prev;
      corr->prev=corr->next;
      corr->next=temp;  
      it->curr=corr;
      corr=corr->prev;
    }
  return;
}
```

output is below - note I have changed the format of node and list as they are now structures defined at the beginning of the example code

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
19
18
17
16
15
14
13
12
11
10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
0
```

(This version does not memory leak. )

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - ok will check - thanks for comment...but before with the `malloc`s and no `free`s it was awful...

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - ok not sure why you saw issue with `valgrind`, I just put the full example through and it works with no issues ... I will put the valgrind output at the end of the answer... -- but it was interesting to put it through its paces on valgrind.

Comment: The code I was looking at was different from the code now present.  I was also looking on a cell phone, not a big screen computer. What I saw had a pair of calls to `free()` at the end.  Those would have been problematic. The code has changed. My comment may but apply any more.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - ok that makes sense it had `malloc`s then `free`s ... in the routine...

Comment: @JonathanLeffler -wow - I put them back and you are correct - `valgrind` complains about bytes lost..   --- ok a bit more investigation and I found out why - the `malloc` and `free` work fine, but in the middle setting the pointer to `next` or `prev` was effectively changing the ammount of memory that the pointer used - so that `free` did not free up all the memory allocated. -- when I then changed the variable names so that memory was allocated and freed without being modified it worked fine.....  ok I really learnt something from that - Jonathan, many thanks for your useful comments :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't update head pointer, I don't know where it is in your code so I will provide example snipper below, rest of the algorithm looks ok:

```
node* head = 0;

void rotate(node** h) {
    node *curr = *h, *tmp = 0;

    while (curr) {
        node* tmp = curr->prev;
        curr->prev = curr->next;
        curr->next = tmp;
        if (!tmp) {
            break;
        }
        curr = tmp;
    }
    //Update head!
    *h = curr;
}

void print(node* head) {
    while (head) {
        printf("%d", head->v);
        head = head->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a C question, please do not provide C++ code as an answer.

Comment: yea, here you go

Comment: Good catch but this is not what question was about

Comment: Thats fair, reverted

Comment: Thank you. Just remove the first 2 lines of the body of your `while` loop, and provide a proper replacement for the OP's function and you will be fine. Your fix seems OK, albeit slightly inefficient as the roving pointer is tested twice.